# $2$-fiber products

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, fibered-products

Let $\cal{C}$ be a $2$-category. Then there is a notion of a $2$-fiber product (see [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-pullback) or [Stacksproject](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/003O)). This notion is quite elaborate and lengthy to define. However, one can try to give a more concise definition.

Namely, if $\cal{C}=\cal{C}at$ is the $2$-category of categories, we define $\mathcal{C}_1\times_{\mathcal{D}}\mathcal{C}_2$ of a diagram $\mathcal{C}_1\xrightarrow{f}\mathcal{D} \xleftarrow{g}\mathcal{C}_2$ to be the category of triples $(c_1, c_2, \phi)$, where $c_1\in \cal{C}_1$, $c_2\in \cal{C}_2$ and $\phi\colon f(c_1)\simeq g(c_2)$ is an isomorphism of their images in $\cal{D}$.

Now, for a general $2$-category $\cal{C}$, we say that a $2$-fiber product $X\times_S Y$ of a diagram $X\xrightarrow{f} S\xleftarrow{g} Y$ is a quadruple $(P, p, q, \phi)$ of an object $P\in \cal{C}$, $1$-morphisms $p\colon P\to X$, $q\colon P\to Y$, and a $2$-isomorphism $\phi\colon f\circ p\simeq g\circ q$ such that, for any object $Z\in\cal{C}$, the natural functor
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z, P) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z, X)\times_{\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z, S)}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z, Y)
$$
is an equivalence of categories.

Is this definition wrong? If it is correct, is there a reason to use the definitions from ncatlab or Stacksproject over this one?

Comment: The notion you define in your second paragraph is properly known as the "iso-comma category", up to isomorphism. Then the notion you define in your third paragraph is an iso-comma object up to equivalence. They are mentioned in the nlab page you cite.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks! But I am a bit confused, the ncatlab page seems to discuss only bi-iso-comma objects and strict iso-comma objects. Does the notion I defined coincide (up to equivalence?) with bi-iso-comma objects? But bi-iso-comma objects seem to be by definition what they call $2$-pullbacks (and what stacksproject calls $2$-fiber products?)

Comment: Yes, you could call them "bi-iso-comma objects". It is not really proper to say whether two notions defined up to equivalence are isomorphic or not, but let me say that bi-iso-comma objects are not isomorphic to bipullbacks. (They are equivalent.)